# testing sails.js with mocha: can't find /api/services/myService

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, sails.js

consider this mocha test:

```
var Sails = require('sails');

describe("Foo Model creation:", function() {
  // create a variable to hold the instantiated sails server
  var app;

  // Global before hook
  before(function(done) {
    // Lift Sails and start the server
    Sails.lift({
      log: {
        level: 'error'
      }
    }, function(err, sails) {
      app = sails;
      done(err, sails);
    });
  });

  // Global after hook
  after(function(done) {
    app.lower(done);
  });

  describe("new foo", function() {
    var foo;
    before(function (cb) {
      var fooData = {
        name: "test foo to be removed after test"
      };

      Foo.create(fooData, function (err, newFoo)              
        if (err) return cb(err);
        foo = newFoo;
        cb();
      });
    });
    it("must show the name", function() {
      foo.must.have.property('name');
    });

    after(function (cb){
      foo.destroy(function (err) {
        cb(err);
      });
    });
  });
})
```

This would work except that the Foo model depends on a sails service i.e. library code defined in /api/services.  Sails, when lifted here, can't find those services.

Is there a way to instruct Sails during a mocha test to also load the services?

Comment: This should work.  What version of Sails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and indeed, Sails *should* be loading services, controllers, etc.

There were some debug tools that helped when lifting Sails:

`Sails.lift({
  log: {
    level: 'verbose'
  },
  appPath: '../',
  // explicitly load almost everything but policies
  //loadHooks: ['moduleloader', 'userconfig', 'orm', 'http', 'controllers', 'services', 'request', 'responses', 'blueprints']
}`

I also did a live debug of Mocha (though I won't go into steps on that here).

What I found out through debugging and a log level of `verbose` (you could also try `silly` if verbose doesn't answer a question) is that I was loading Sails from the wrong directory - the test directory.  Once I changed appPath to '../', I could tell from the log messages that it was loading the proper content, and voila, my sails.services.myService object was now there!

Hope that helps!